# Hibernate ehCache no working

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, ehcache

we are trying to use ehCache in our application but for some reason it does not seem to work,
We get no exceptions but when viewing the liveCacheStatistics we see no hits, no misss, nothing.

I anotated the entitys in this mannar:

```
@Entity
@Cacheable
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Table(name = "Table_NAME")
public class MyEntity implements Serializable
{
 // some code here..
}
```

I make sure that this entity is being requested more then once.

Then i brakepoint and look at

```
CacheManager.getInstance().getCache(cacheName).getLiveCacheStatistics().liveDelegate
```

And its all zeros.

What could be the problom here? what am I missing?

Thx in advance.

Comment: How did you configure Hibernate to work with EhCache (in your.cfg.xml file)? What is your Hibernate version?

Comment: 4.2.6
According to the docs in ehCach site
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory</property>